# count object values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, count

I am facing an issue in javascript. I want to count object value if `firstname` and `lastname` in both values are present in object then count object value.

```js
var person = [{  firstName : "John",lastName  : "Doe"},
{  lastName  : "Alex"},
{  firstName : "John"},
{  firstName : "Smith",lastName  : "Tom"}];

for(var i=0;i<person.length; i++){
  console.log(person[i]);
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
count: 2 (both values are present)

{  firstName : "John",lastName  : "Doe"},
{  firstName : "Smith",lastName  : "Tom"}
```

what should i do?
anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The first step is to write an `if` condition inside the for loop instead of just logging.

Comment: `person.forEach(p => p.firstName && p.lastName && count++);`

Comment: nope, how can i do using `if condition` [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3082296/adiga)

Comment: hasOwnProperty  might help you to check if an object has an attribute  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: @Yousaf, check against `undefined` because keys could exist with values `0`, `null`, `false`...

Answer (score 0):

you can check if firstName and lastName are present in the object as such:

```
   if(person[i].firstName !== undefined && person[i].lastName != undefined) {
      console.log(person[i]);
   }
```

Comment: check against `undefined` because keys could exist with values `0`, `null`, `false`...

Comment: thanks [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11671574/tushar)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method the filter out invalid person objects

```js
const persons = [
  { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" },
  { lastName: "Alex" },
  { firstName: "John" },
  { firstName: "Smith", lastName: "Tom" }
];

// Check if the person object has the properties firstName & lastName
const validPersons = persons.filter((person) => person.hasOwnProperty("firstName") && person.hasOwnProperty("lastName"));

// Count
console.log(validPersons.length);

// Total object
console.log(validPersons);
```

Comment: check against `undefined` because keys could exist with values `0`, `null`, `false`...

Comment: @iAmOren those are falsy values and they will be filtered out by the if statement. See: [boolean](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp). Scroll down to: Everything Without a "Value" is False

Comment: run your function against this:
`var persons = [
  {  firstName : 0, lastName : "Doe"},
  {  firstName : null , lastName : "Doe"},
  {  firstName : false, lastName : "Doe"},
  {  firstName : "", lastName : "Doe"},
  {  firstName : undefined, lastName : "Doe"}
];` - it will return nothing, even though all 5 items are objects with *BOTH* keys defined.

Comment: thanks [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3257622/theblackgigant)

Answer (score 0):

Check if keys are not undefined:

```
for(var i=0; i<person.length; i++) {
  if((person[i].firstName!=undefined) && (person[i].lastName!=undefined))
    console.log(person[i]);
}
```

check against `undefined` because keys could exist with values `0`, `null`, `false`...

Comment: thanks [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5792509/iamoren)

Comment: Great!  Here, at SO, points are awarded for selected and up-voted answers (among other things) - please do so, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var person = [{  firstName : "John",lastName  : "Doe"},
{  lastName  : "Alex"},
{  firstName : "John"},
{  firstName : "Smith",lastName  : "Tom"}];

let count = 0;
for(var i=0;i<person.length; i++){
  if (person[i].hasOwnProperty("lastName") && person[i].hasOwnProperty("firstName")){
    if(person[i].lastName !== "" && person[i].firstName !== "")
      count++;
  }
}

console.log(count)
```

You can replace value check conditions **person[i].lastName !== ""**, according to your empty values

Comment: thanks [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8489777/ara)

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do what you require, it will iterate through the person object and find if each have *firstName* & *lastName* key value pairs, if so it increments the value of count by 1 and saves the result in variable '*result*'.
Towards the end you can get the total count in '*count*' variable and your filtered results(the objects which has firstName & lastName key : value pairs) in the '*result*' object.

```
   var person = [{  firstName : "John",lastName  : "Doe"},
    {  lastName  : "Alex"},
    {  firstName : "John"},
    {  firstName : "Smith",lastName  : "Tom"}];
    
    var count = 0;
    var result = [{}];//It is an Array of objects

    for(var i=0;i<person.length; i++){// To iterate through each person object
      if(person[i].firstName && person[i].lastName)//Check if the object has firstName & lastName key : value pairs
      {              
          result[count] = person[i];// Insert the object into result
          ++count;//On meeting the criteria increment the value of count by 1
      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11259567/akhil-das-panicker)